# Vue3 css variable injection

Tags: sass, vuejs3

I’ve seen we can use variable injection to our style using [this](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/231)

However, I’m not managing at all to pass any variable given that the setup uses Vue3 and the style is scoped and using lang="scss". Here below an example of how I did it:

```
<template>
    <header class="header">
        Hello
    </header>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    setup(props) {
        return {
            myColor: 'red',
            }
    },
}
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.header {
    color: v-bind(myColor);
}
</style>
```

any ideas?